# Arranging Peoples In A Row

Tags: combinatorics

Why when we need to put 2 people together we calculate them as one unit and not two?
They have 2 ways to sit one near the other, but why we reduce just 1 from the overall number of peoples?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to count.  If you're trying to count how many ways can you choose two people, then it doesn't matter which chair the two go in, person 1 followed by person 2 is the same two people as person 2 followed by person 1.  However, if order _does_ matter, then you do need to count this twice.

Comment: If you want all of the different orders for $n$ people to sit in a row such that two specific people always sit next to each other, then you do treat them as a single unit.  So you would find there are $(n - 1)!$ ways of seating them.  Presumably order matters here, so for each of the $(n - 1)!$ there are $2! = 2$ ways to arrange the two people, so the final count would be $2!(n - 1)!$ (so you _do_ account for the two ways they could sit next to each other).